# Bizarre SDcard MMC errors

Tags: boot, sd-card, boot-issues, pi-2

I'm seeing strange issues on the Raspberry Pi B2.

```
[   85.426681] request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000
[   85.428508] request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000
[   85.449229] request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000
[   85.449778] request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000
[   85.472247] [<800256f8>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<80410298>] (bcm2835_mmc_transfer_dma+0x1a8/0x1e0)
[   85.485867] [<80410298>] (bcm2835_mmc_transfer_dma) from [<80411324>] (bcm2835_mmc_request+0xa8/0xc0)
[   85.498750] [<80411324>] (bcm2835_mmc_request) from [<803f9aa8>] (mmc_start_request+0xd4/0xf8)
[   85.511034] [<803f9aa8>] (mmc_start_request) from [<803fa834>] (mmc_start_req+0x2a8/0x37c)
[   85.523053] [<803fa834>] (mmc_start_req) from [<804090a4>] (mmc_blk_issue_rw_rq+0xc8/0xafc)
[   85.535168] [<804090a4>] (mmc_blk_issue_rw_rq) from [<80409bdc>] (mmc_blk_issue_rq+0x104/0x4d8)
[   85.547683] [<80409bdc>] (mmc_blk_issue_rq) from [<8040aedc>] (mmc_queue_thread+0xb8/0x158)
[   85.559891] [<8040aedc>] (mmc_queue_thread) from [<8003ffa0>] (kthread+0xe0/0xfc)
[   85.571240] [<8003ffa0>] (kthread) from [<8000eb88>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
[   85.580610] ---[ end trace f869ecbd2c135221 ]---
[   85.587513] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #5515: comm udevd: bad extra_isize (5787 != 256)
[   85.587572] mmcblk0: unknown error -5 sending read/write command, card status 0x900
[   85.587586] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2048
[   95.597794] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[   95.605645] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 801952, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
[   95.620166] mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
```

### This reproduces:

- On all B2s
- But *not* on A+s or B+s
- On all of my Samsung EVO 16GB sdcards
- But not on sdcards of other brands
- And not on my 32GB EVO sdcard
- Randomly (only reproducible 50% of the time)

### It:

- Is non fatal (just cycle power, and 50% chance it'll boot normally. If not, try again)
- Leads to permanent corruption (eventually the sdcards are left unmountable)

## Steps to reproduce

1. Download the latest Raspbian
2. Burn to EVO sdcard with `Win32 Disk Imager`
3. Put in card and apply 5V power (w/ 2.4A PSU)
4. Pi may very well crash on first boot.

## What I know

- [This person](http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/e456459d879e22822b972ae69412f9bb-ab4c8741528c4f61da0c49f49af9cc12) seems to be having the same issue (with details)
- People [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) seem to be having mixed results with EVO cards (but details are scarce)
- The error mentions `bcm2835`, but the B2 runs a `bcm2836`. Idk. Maybe they share MMC code? I wouldn't be surprised.
- I know the following about the cards:

  ```
  pi@isengard ~ $ cd /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc?/mmc?:*
  pi@isengard /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:59b4 $ echo "man:$(cat manfid) oem:$(cat oemid) name:$(cat name) hwrev:$(cat hwrev) fwrev:$(cat fwrev)"
  man:0x00001b oem:0x534d name:00000 hwrev:0x1 fwrev:0x0
  ```

---

Normally, I'd just switch to a different sdcard and move on with my life, but this is for a very large project (>200pis). I'd very much like to know what's going on, if it's fixable, and if I should start moving the project over to new hardware. If you can't help, consider an upvote. The rep will go towards a bounty.

Comment: I've come across this problem on all EVO-16 (Orange) Cards. However the EVO Pro Cards don't seem to suffer from this problem. I have 4 (1 Pro, 3 Orange) Pi's in a monitor matrix running and occasionally they will fail to boot. Except the one that is booting from the Pro (16GB) card. The OS is Raspbian, I haven't tried any other OS but the problem is very common on the EVO (Orange) line. Adding rootdelay to cmdline.txt does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a bug in the Raspberry Pi firmware. See [raspberrypi/firmware #397](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fraspberrypi%2Ffirmware%2Fissues%2F397).

Running `sudo rpi-update` to upgrade to the latest firmware will fix the issue.